# Trouble on migrating in production mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the Capistrano gem and I created a migration file in order to change database table column names. When in my local machine I run the `rake db:migrate` command (in `development` mode) it works, but I would like to make effective these changes on the remote server in `production` mode. **My problem is**: *if I run the Capistrano command `cap deploy:migrate` I get the following error message in the production log file on the remote server* :

```
* executing "cd /<my_application_path>/releases/20111025205951 && rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate"
  servers: ["<my_application_IP>"]
  [<my_application_IP>] executing command
 ** [out :: <my_remote_server_IP>] (in /<my_application_path>/releases/20111025205951)
*** [err :: <my_remote_server_IP>] rake aborted!
*** [err :: <my_remote_server_IP>] uninitialized constant Rake::DSL
*** /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/tasklib.rb:8:in `<class:TaskLib>'
*** ...
```

**How can I solve the problem?** Is it related to using Ruby version 1.9.1 as outputted in the above error message?

---

*Note*: If I run the `ruby -v` command

```
# on the local machine (MacOS running Snow Leopard 10.6.7) I get
>> ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.7.0]
# on the remote machine (Linux running Ubuntu 10.04 LTS) I get
>> ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [i686-linux]
```

---

**UPDATE** for *@Simone Carletti*

After I added the `require 'bundler/capistrano'` at the top of the `deploy.rb` file and after I run the `cap deploy:migrations` command I get the following error:

```
...
* executing "cd /<my_application_path>/releases/20111026132212 && bundle install --gemfile /<my_application_path>/releases/20111026132212/Gemfile --path /<my_application_path>/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
  servers: ["<my_remote_server_IP>"]
  [<my_remote_server_IP>] executing command
** [out :: <my_remote_server_IP>] Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
** [out :: <my_remote_server_IP>] Could not find libv8-3.3.10.2 in any of the sources
   command finished in 2554ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /<my_application_path>/releases/20111026132212 && bundle install --gemfile /<my_application_path>/releases/20111026132212/Gemfile --path /<my_application_path>/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on <my_remote_server_IP>
```

**What does this mean?** It may be related to the last part (that is, the `N.B.` part) of the following text? If so, what I should do?

When I run the `cap -e bundle:install` command (from the [official documentation](http://gembundler.com/deploying.html)) I get:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
cap bundle:install
------------------------------------------------------------
Install the current Bundler environment. By default, gems will be installed to
the shared/bundle path. Gems in the development and test group will not be
installed. The install command is executed with the --deployment and --quiet
flags. If the bundle cmd cannot be found then you can override the bundle_cmd
variable to specifiy which one it should use.

You can override any of these defaults by setting the variables shown below.

N.B. bundle_roles must be defined before you require 'bundler/capistrano' in
your deploy.rb file.

  set :bundle_gemfile,  "Gemfile"
  set :bundle_dir,      File.join(fetch(:shared_path), 'bundle')
  set :bundle_flags,    "--deployment --quiet"
  set :bundle_without,  [:development, :test]
  set :bundle_cmd,      "bundle" # e.g. "/opt/ruby/bin/bundle"
  set :bundle_roles,    {:except => {:no_release => true}} # e.g. [:app, :batch]
```

*Note*: The `cap deploy:migrations` command created an empty `/<my_application_path>/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1` directory with a `755` pemission.

Comment: did you try; `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`

Comment: @apneadiving - Are you sure it is sure? In the past I run something starting with `bundle exec ...` and I got some serious problems (that I don't remember)...

Comment: `bundle exec` is just meant to execute the version of rake from your rails app, it solves some compatibility issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the guilty.

```
rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate
```

You should run

```
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=production  db:migrate
```

Make sure you are including the `bundler/capistrano` recipes in your `deploy.rb` file.

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
```

These recipes will change the command for you. See [Automatic deployment with Capistrano](http://gembundler.com/deploying.html).

Comment: So (just to be sure),  should I add the `require "bundler/capistrano"` at the top of the `deploy.rb` file?

Comment: Yes, exactly, or just before any custom recipe that uses `rake`.

Comment: I updated the question with a new error that I'm getting on deploying my application.

Comment: Have you any solution to the new problem?

Comment: It's not that simple to be solved. It requires debugging on the server end. I'm sorry, but this is not a simple problem->answer question. It was the original one, in fact I provided you the solution. I encourage you to dig into the internals of Bundler and check why it fails.

Comment: I opened a specific question for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7905519/trouble-on-deploying-with-bundler-and-capistrano. Thanks anyway.