# Trouble on deploying with Bundler and Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, capistrano

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and the Capistrano gem. As wrote in the [Bundler official documentation](http://gembundler.com/deploying.html) in the "Automatic deployment with Capistrano" section, I added the `require 'bundler/capistrano'` to the top of my `deploy.rb` file.

Now, when I run the `cap deploy:migrations` command (Deploy and run pending migrations) I get the following error:

```
...
* executing "cd /<my_application_path>/releases/20111026132212 && bundle install --gemfile /<my_application_path>/releases/20111026132212/Gemfile --path /<my_application_path>/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test"
  servers: ["<my_remote_server_IP>"]
  [<my_remote_server_IP>] executing command
** [out :: <my_remote_server_IP>] Some gems seem to be missing from your vendor/cache directory.
** [out :: <my_remote_server_IP>] Could not find libv8-3.3.10.2 in any of the sources
   command finished in 2554ms
failed: "sh -c 'cd /<my_application_path>/releases/20111026132212 && bundle install --gemfile /<my_application_path>/releases/20111026132212/Gemfile --path /<my_application_path>/shared/bundle --deployment --quiet --without development test'" on <my_remote_server_IP>
```

**How can I solve the problem?**

*Note*: This is a specific question of a related problem I started to have after [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7902425/trouble-on-migrating-in-production-mode).

Comment: I have the exact same problem! You managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your local Gemlock file may be out of sync with your remote gemset. If you've recently added gems, make sure you run `bundle install` on your local fileset to update the Gemlock file, then check in those changes (if any). Re-run the deployment.

Comment: I made that (`bundle install`) and re-deploy, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you install the libv8 javascript engine? Maybe the problem is that the gem requiring the v8 engine is failing to find the library and therefore not loading properly.

Comment: How can I check if on my remote machine (running Ubuntu 10.04) the libv8 javascript engine is installed?